# Why the GUI looks different in Swing designer and when it's running?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Firstly, thanks for your reading. I'm learning how to use Swing designer and some stuff about Swing.  Sorry for my rookie question.

In designer:
[image: in the SWT designer]

When it is running:
[image: during it's running]

I tried to draw a GUI in Swing designer. But it all changed while running. The location and size of the buttons in the left side have been changed severely. Is it because of the System resolution?  Thanks for helping!

```
package GUI;
public class FlowerFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FlowerFrame window = new FlowerFrame();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public FlowerFrame() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("销售统计");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 824, 497);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JButton button = new JButton("\u663E\u793A\u5E93\u5B58");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_button = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_button.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_button.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_button.gridx = 2;
    gbc_button.gridy = 1;
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, gbc_button);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("\u9500\u552E\u56FE\u8868");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_button_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_button_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_button_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_button_1.gridx = 8;
    gbc_button_1.gridy = 1;
    frame.getContentPane().add(button_1, gbc_button_1);

    JButton button_2 = new JButton("\u4FDD\u5B58\u5E76\u9000\u51FA");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_button_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_button_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_button_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_button_2.gridx = 13;
    gbc_button_2.gridy = 1;
    frame.getContentPane().add(button_2, gbc_button_2);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textArea.gridheight = 8;
    gbc_textArea.gridwidth = 14;
    gbc_textArea.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textArea.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_textArea.gridx = 2;
    gbc_textArea.gridy = 2;
    frame.getContentPane().add(textArea, gbc_textArea);

    JButton button_3 = new JButton("\u63D0\u4EA4");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_button_3 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_button_3.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_button_3.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_button_3.gridx = 2;
    gbc_button_3.gridy = 11;
    frame.getContentPane().add(button_3, gbc_button_3);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("\u552E\u8D27\u5458");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_label.gridx = 8;
    gbc_label.gridy = 11;
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, gbc_label);

    textField = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textField.gridx = 10;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 11;
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc_textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("\u5546\u54C1\u7F16\u53F7");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_label_1.gridx = 8;
    gbc_label_1.gridy = 12;
    frame.getContentPane().add(label_1, gbc_label_1);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField_1.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc_textField_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textField_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textField_1.gridx = 10;
    gbc_textField_1.gridy = 12;
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_1, gbc_textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    JButton button_4 = new JButton("\u6E05\u7A7A");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_button_4 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_button_4.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_button_4.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_button_4.gridx = 2;
    gbc_button_4.gridy = 13;
    frame.getContentPane().add(button_4, gbc_button_4);

    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("\u6570\u91CF");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_label_2.gridx = 8;
    gbc_label_2.gridy = 13;
    frame.getContentPane().add(label_2, gbc_label_2);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField_2.gridwidth = 6;
    gbc_textField_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_textField_2.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_textField_2.gridx = 10;
    gbc_textField_2.gridy = 13;
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField_2, gbc_textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);
}

}
```

Comment: I think you'll want to have a look at [Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)